# Google Sheets : Group By one column and Rank by 2 columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, group-by, rank, ranking-functions

I have a table like below where I need to group by column A and determine rank/priority based on the logic below:

These are the steps I would like to do :

- First Group by column A
- Then check column B for each group. The lower the start date, the smaller the rank for example if the dates are 2022 and 2023, 2022 will get rank 1 and 2023 will get rank 2 and so on ...
- If the start years are the same for rows, then check column C and assign rank based on the Impact. Higher the impact, lower the rank. For example if 2 rows have start year 2022 then if impact is 100 for one row and 50 for the other, impact with 100 will get rank 1 and 50 will get rank 2 and so on ...

[Please see picture for sample data and expected output in column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNC9w.png)

I have tried this function but it only gives me rank based on one column - https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/rank-group-wise-in-google-sheets/

Also clarifying that Column D is what I would like to generate through the formula. I was just showing that as expected output in the image. We don't have that available and need to generate that rank from columns A, B and C!

Any ideas/thoughts are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please , include your sheet take a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the lower the year that gets the higher rank. OR  The lower the start date, the smaller the rank ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
=SORT(A2:D13,1,1,2,1,3,0)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Read about [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been clear. Column D is what I would like to generate through the formula. I was just showing that as expected output. We don't have that available and need to generate that rank from columns A, B and C!

Comment: I bet you didn't even try the formula @VarshaVenkatraman . As mentioned: *(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)* . Then, give it a try. Also. Please read about [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: I did try it but in your formula you reference column D. I do not actually have column D in my table. That is the column that needs to be generated. It is not about just sorting the values, I need to generate the rank in column D based on columns A, B and C and the logic outlined in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, 
 {SORT(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, A2:A, 1, B2:B, 1, C2:C, 0), 
 COUNTIFS(SORT(A2:A), SORT(A2:A), ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]